# Set percentage width in a table-cell element without specify the table elemen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

As we all know,the percentage width is relative to the table element.But what if I don't specify a table element?I try to set `width:1%` to the table-cell element, it strangely fill the size of the wrapper element.But when I set `width:100%`,it seems that it didn't change anything.What's the reason behind that?What's the anonymous table element's actual width?

```css
.wrap{
  background:red;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
  width:1%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cell">content in here.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its strange that if you increase value of `width` from `1%` to `10%` to `50%` to `100%`, the width keeps on decreasing.

Comment: Yep.I have figured out what's going on.Go a look at W3C spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#auto-table-layout and you will know.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not alter the width of a non-existing element.**

Render a page with a `<td>` element without a `<table>`.

Have a look to the page's source code.

The `<td>` element is not there, just its content.

The [WHATWG's specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-td-element) defines that `<td>` can be used in `<tr>` which, in turn, can be used in `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` or `<table>`.

> **4.9.9 The td element**
>
> *Contexts in which this element can be used*:
>
> As a child of a tr element.

A `<td>` without a `<tr>` (and a `<tr>` without `<table>`) is not valid HTML, you are reliying on the browser's implementation.

With most of the browsers that means:

```
<table> <td> Text </td> </table>
```

renders to:

```
<table> <tbody> <tr> <td> Text </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

but

```
<tr> <td> Text </td> </tr>
```

renders to:

```
Text
```

Comment: No,I don't think so.
`<tr><td> Text </td></tr>`
will renders to:
`<table><tr><td> Text </td></tr></table>`

Comment: @gdut-zdc: and why you don't think so? I tested my answer under FF 40, Chrome 45, Opera 32, IE 11, Edge and Safari 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works in my mind:

Think of an element with a `table-cell`property as a `<td>` element, so, what is the 100% width of a table cell? Normally, it's something like you get by defining the full width in percentage (or leaving the value as default). So, by lowering the digit you are forcing the element to behave less like a cell.

Hope that makes sense to you.